# Sink Drain Stopper Removal - Cannot Unscrew a piece of plastic is stopping me from unscrewing it

Tags: drain, sink

I am trying to unscrew the connector for the sink drain stopper, but a piece of plastic is in the way. I am not sure how they got it on the first place with this plastic in the way.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's anything to unscrew. This looks like a spring-fit clamp that you'd simply flex off its locking tabs.

There's no water pressure on these ball seals, so it doesn't take much to keep them from leaking.

Comment: Thank you for your help and time! I am trying to pull/push it off, and it just will not move. I am not getting any flex. Should I just brute force it off?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: It would be _super_ helpful to the next @Joe who comes along if you would be so kind as to post what you did. If I've run into the same problem, reading "never mind, I figured it out" isn't very helpful... Heck, you could even post your own answer in the "Your Answer" box and earn a few magical interwebz points redeemable for unicorns and rainbows!

Comment: Did it involve a tiny silver-colored screw visible on top of the fitting, perhaps?